# What is this type of webpart called and how do I create it?

Tags: sharepoint

I need to create a library for meeting minutes and agendas exactly like [image]

So basically I need a library that organizes meeting minutes and agendas by fiscal year, then Team name.

Any help pointing me in the right direction would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The web part is called a List View Web part.

To create one, first create a document library and add the relevant columns by which you want to organize the documents. Optionally, you can then create a view (or modify an existing view) in the library to display the documents grouped by the desired columns.

Once the library has been created, you can show it on any page by adding its list view web part to that page.

Every view that you create in the library automatically gets its own page with the appropriate list view web part already added.